Cosmic Byte Quantum gaming controller's gyroscope not work over Bluetooth on Android
I’m having an issue with my gaming controller - Cosmic Byte Quantum and was hoping someone could help. Here’s the situation:

Device Setup: I have Cosmic Byte Quantum gaming controller that I connect to my Samsung Galaxy Tab S8+ using Bluetooth.

Problem: The gyroscope on the controller doesn’t seem to be working when connected via Bluetooth. Checked it using Game controller tester App

Observation/Temporary Fix: When I connect the controller to my tablet via USB, the gyroscope works perfectly.

Interesting Observation: If I connect the same controller to my iPhone via Bluetooth, the gyroscope functions correctly without any issues.


Given this, I have a few questions:

Why does the gyroscope work via USB but not Bluetooth on my Android tablet?

Is there a compatibility issue between Android and the controller’s Bluetooth connection?

Could it be a problem with how Android handles Bluetooth devices versus how iOS does?



Why does the gyroscope work over Bluetooth on my iPhone but not on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S8+?

Does iOS have better support for Bluetooth gyroscope functionality?


What can be done to solve this issue?

Are there any settings or apps on Android that I can tweak to fix the gyroscope issue?

Can I root the tab and tweak something to fix this?

Any other alternates, like buying a USB Dongle for the controller can fix this?




Any insights, suggestions, or solutions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help!
What did I try:

Tried updating the firmware of the controller

Tried using other apps/games to test Gyro

Tried other Android devices


Expectation:

Get the gyro from the controller working so as to play games like asphalt8 and others using the Controller's Gyroscope


If the BT communication works in general then buying additional hardware will not change anything as the BT device is only responsible for sending and receiving BT packets. Decoding and data interpretation is a software thing and thus is most likely done by the BT stack or some application level software.

Welcome. Considering this community is about Android, we probably aren't the best community to ask about iOS. However, we have a sister site [apple.se] for Apple products, including iOS, in case you're interested.

If you are interested in checking your controller on BT level you can use nRF connect app
which allows to display the supported services and characteristics of a BT device. Knowing them (especially the UUIDs shown by the app) would it allow to search for entries in Google issue tracker if there are known problems with type of device.

@Robert I've done a similar check using the Game controller tester App. The actual confusion here is why/how does the gyro work on bluetooth for iOS and not on android. What can be really done to fix it. Maybe, consider updating controller drivers on my tab?

My comment wasn't for checking if it works it was for identifying which characteristics are provided by your device thus which Bluetooth protocol standards are used. May be Android doesn't implement the Gyro characteristics then you can not change this or the apps you have used for testing don't make use of this specific characteristics. The nrf connect app just shows the available characteristics. Knowing them would allow to start an internet search for the reason why it doesn't work.
